# How to correct this Callable statement?

Tags: java

```
Callable<Response> myTask = () -> {
            return queryService.queryGraph(inputInfo);
        };
```

I am creating a new Callable thread and use this syntax, but received a message that "Statement lambda can be replaced with expression lambda". Also in Intellij, there is a little sign in the editor which says "Override method in "java.util.concurrent.Callable".

How to get rid of these two messages?

Comment: Maybe it just wants you to get rid of the block, so `myTask = () -> queryService.queryGraph(inputInfo);`. Yours should work fine though, it's just syntax.

Comment: That's just a warning indicating you can use a simpler syntax here.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the second message. It's not a warning. It's just telling you that you are overriding a method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this warning as you can reduce the lamda by removing `{}` `retrun` and it will still do the same job. Use :

```
 Callable<Response> myTask = () -> queryService.queryGraph(inputInfo);
```

Instead of :

```
Callable<Response> myTask = () -> {
            return queryService.queryGraph(inputInfo);
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is fine. I think that's intellij to warning you to not introduce unnecessary brackets:

```
Callable<Response> myTask = () -> queryService.queryGraph(inputInfo);
```

Because you can collapse single statement lambda body.

Hint: In Intellij you can use `Alt + Enter` to see the correct suggestion of IDE